# Hibernate Many To Many unidirectional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two tables USERS and FILES. I want to be able to control the users that can download a file, and for this I was thinking of creating and intermediary table FILE_PERMISSIONS with a user_id and a file_id.

Looking at database level I understand how can I solve the problem, but going up at Hibernate level, I can't really understand how should I map this relation. The way I see it is something like this:

```
public class User {
   private Integer userId;
}

public class File {
   private Integer fileId;
   private List<Integer> userIds;
}
```

So I want my File object to know the id property of all the users that can download the file, but not vice versa, so that a user doesn't know about those files.

From what I read I can use a many to many unidirectional relation but I'm not sure that I can only have the id of the user, and not the user object itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage it having the following structure.

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Integer userId;

    // getters, setters
}
```

File:

```
@Entity
public class File {
    @Id
    private Integer fileId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "file_permissions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "file_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private Set<User> users;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to update a user fields, create new users during saving a file?

Comment: To change this behaviour  you can play with `insertable` and `updatable` flags of `@JoinColumn` annotation.

Comment: Just remove `cascade`. That's enough.

Comment: Thank you, @OleksandrShpota! I have two questions tho. First is why you use a Set and not a List and the second one is: For example if I select a file, hibernate will not only create a File object, it will also create a number n of User objects that cand download this file. Am I right?

Comment: 1) It does not really make a big difference, I used Set because it is close to the real business situation - it does not make sense to have duplicates in collection of users. You can use List if it feets better with your model.
2) Not exactly. By default here hibernate uses so-called lazy loading mechanism. It means that if you load a file hibernate will not load the users. It will load them only when you first invoke `getUsers()` method. You can control this behaviour by changing [fetch parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#fetch--) of `@ManyToMany`

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from making an easier design using @OneToMany relationship instead. This way you could create a service in order to manage File permissions, instead of relying on user service or file services to do so.

I propose something like:

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FilePermissions> filePermissionsList= new ArrayList<>();


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<FilePermissions> getFilePermissionsList() {
        return filePermissionsList;
    }

    public void setFilePermissionsList(List<FilePermissions> filePermissionsList) {
        this.filePermissionsList = filePermissionsList;
    }
}
```

Notice User has a list of FilePermissions.

Your FilePermission class should be like:

```
@Entity
public class FilePermissions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    private File file;

    private Permission permission;


    public FilePermissions() {

    }

    public FilePermissions(User user, File file, Permission permission) {
        this.user = user;
        this.file = file;
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public Permission getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public void setPermission(Permission permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }
}
```

Notice the @ManytoOne relationship back to the user, as well as the @OneToOne relationship to the File class. Here you can store the detail on what permission user have, in this case i have a enumeration.

Your File class is straight forward:

```
@Entity
public class File {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private String name;

    public File() {}

    public File(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You can see solution in detail here: https://github.com/ccoloradoc/HibernateFilePermissionSample